# How is docker cache images data?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have two project. For all of them I have create docker-compose.yml for DEV environment.

At first I worked with project 1 and everything was good. But then I have build images for project 2 and docker somehow have cached nginx image from project 1 to project.

So, I have found inside container of project 2 files from project 1 in directory /etc/nginx/conf.d/.

Project 1 and project 2 have similar docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile for nginx.

How I can prevent this behavior? How is docker cache images data?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
  nginx:
    build: ./docker/dev/nginx
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/application
    links:
      - php
  php:
    build: ./docker/dev/php
    volumes:
      - ./:/application
    links:
      - mariadb
      - mongo
...
```

**project1/docker/dev/nginx/Dockerfile (or project 2, ther are same)**

```
FROM nginx:1.10

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Comment: Can't you give your nginx image of project2 a different name then the nginx image of project1? under the `build: ./docker/dev/nginx` add     `image: nginx-1` or am I misunderstanding the issue? Or executing docker-compose with --build option which will rebuild everything, but this won't be a real solution if you use a different image with the same name in 2 projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you start docker-compose you need use flag `--build` this flag says docker-compose build containers every time, not use old if they similar

Example: `docker-compose up --build` when you end with this `docker-compose down`